# Setting configuration values at runtime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm using laravel 5.8 and created a command that runs in the background to keep data updated.

web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/do_stuff', function () {
    Artisan::call('do:stuff');
    return 'Started!';
});
```

DoStuff.php

```
while(config('key.value')){
  doStuff();
  sleep(120);
}
```

Also got my route (mysite.com/admin/do_stuff) that will start this process, but now I want to add a new route (mysite.com/admin/stop_doing_stuff) to be able to stop it. I've seen in the documentation config variables could be set during runtime https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#accessing-configuration-values but this doesn't seem to be changing the value at all. Is this possible?

Reading the value from the .env file seems to work but that means I need to edit that file manually and that's not an option, also I could store the value in the database but would like to not doing it. Tried clearing the config cache but getting the same result

Comment: take a look here: https://www.egeniq.com/blog/how-gracefully-stop-laravel-cli-command

Comment: @Nasa thanks for that, seems quite a nice way to achieve it. I presume signals can be called from a route perhaps